# Block device naming, how to enable by-name and by-uuid?

Tags: linux, embedded, android

While building and using linux kernel for custom boards, when Android is used, usually the MMC partitions appear in `/dev/block/mmcblkXpY`. And there are also symbolic links created in `/dev/block/**/<by-name or by-uuid>` etc. This mapping is seen in Ubuntu for hard disk partitions.

When I am using openwrt, the mmc block device appear as `/dev/mmcblkXpY`. Is this behavior somehow configurable? Is this done from userspace?

Answer (score 1):

On "modern" Linux systems `/dev` is normally populated by [udev](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Udev). According to https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-user/base-system/hotplug#coldplug OpenWrt no longer uses `udev`.